# Asp.Net MVC MapRoute with optional language URL segment

Tags: asp.net, url, routes, segment

I have an ASP.Net MVC app with following routes mapping:

```
context.MapRoute("Empty","", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute("Info","/Info", new { controller = "Info", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute("Base","/Info/Base", new { controller = "Info", action = "Base" });
```

I need to add a language prefix to URL as segment in order to URL looks like that:

```
www.something.com/en
www.something.com/en/Info
www.something.com/en/Info/Base
```

I easily achieve it with adding the languageCode param to URL:

```
context.MapRoute("Empty","/{languageCode}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute("Info","/{languageCode}/Info", new { controller = "Info", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute("Base","/{languageCode}/Info/Base", new { controller = "Info", action = "Base" });
```

Infortunately, this parameter should be optional. But when I miss it in URL under those routes - I have 404 error.

Any ideas how to implement it ? Adding languageCode = UrlParameter.Optional is not helping, it works only if optional parameter is trailing URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add both route configurations (with and without `languageCode`) and you will have the desired behavior

```
context.MapRoute("Empty","/{languageCode}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute("Info","/{languageCode}/Info", new { controller = "Info", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute("Base","/{languageCode}/Info/Base", new { controller = "Info", action = "Base" });
context.MapRoute("Empty","", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute("Info","/Info", new { controller = "Info", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute("Base","/Info/Base", new { controller = "Info", action = "Base" });
```

**Note**

The following configuration is equal to yours, but contains less configuration code (but it will also expose all other controllers)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LanguageCode",
    url: "{languageCode}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. My problem was in ordering the MapRoutes. Each "language-defined" shall be following by "non-language-defined".